# Get tcm-id by webdav in tridion

Tags: javascript, tridion

I'm trying to implement tridion GUI extension. And I need to get tcm-id of the page template.
How do I get it having WebDAV in javascript?

Comment: Please ask this question in the SDL Tridion Stack Exchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: I also helps if you include code showing what you've already tried. There are quite some questions covering how to get the ID of many items already, so your code provides context of why you're stuck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tridion, so should be asked on tridion.stackexchange.com.